# How to change email in google sign in

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin

```
signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
    }
});
```

Its same for everyone for signing in but how do I change an email of an existing user from the app?

```
public class AccountSettings extends Fragment {

View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_account, container, false);

    Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.change);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String mEmail = user.getEmail();

            user.updateEmail(mEmail)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.d("TAAAAGGGG", "User email address updated.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

 return rootView;
}

}
```

..............................................................................................................

Comment: What do you mean? The app starts a Google sign in process - either the user is already authenticated with Google or the sign-in process will ask for the user name.

Comment: Yeah... when the user is signed in how do i add a feature to let the user change that email?

Comment: The Google Login will provide that possibility ("use another account")

Comment: Not log into another accounnt... transfer all the existing data to a new email @Henry

Comment: @MichelleKinsten are you referring to firebase change account?

Comment: Yeah @PradyumanDixit

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-authenticate your user. As according to documentation changing primary email address is a sensitive action.

For re-authenticating, you can use a code like this, `result` variable has `GoogleSignInResult` on successful signIn.

```java
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

// credential
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");

                            //Now change your email address

                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: should the UID come in user@example.com?

Comment: No the email ID @MichelleKinsten, if you are giving user the ability to change his email id then the first code would work too, if you as developer/admin of the app are doing the deed, you will need the second code.

Comment: No im not doing it i want to give the user the feature... So the getEmail method will getch the email of the user so i should just put that in there?

Comment: Yes, it should work, you can try the first code and see if everything goes as decided @MichelleKinsten

Comment: i have updated my code and it doesnt work... what have i missed? when i click the button nothing happens

Comment: mine is google authentication and not email password so can u update ur code to that pleasee

Comment: @MichelleKinsten I have updated the code, but I'm not. sure it would work, because there is no such info on Firebase docs, you may try and tell if it works or not.

Comment: result variable has GoogleSignInResult from signIn `GoogleSignInResult result `

Comment: null pointer exception for result....
i declared GoogleSignInResult result; probably cuz i havnt initialised... what should the code be? im sorry but there is no info on the internet and i have no idea how to proceed